# Query delete in Firestore is deleting everything, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I need to remove all docs from a collection, but I should delete only where 'pedido' equals to 'this.pProdutos'. The problem is that, even after querying, it does delete all the docs in the entire collection.
I am using this code below right now:

```
    this.db.collection('produtosPedidos', ref => ref.where('pedido', '==', this.pProdutos)).ref
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        doc.ref.delete().then(() => {
          console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Comment: have you tried to list documents from querySnapshot? is this entire collection? If so, there could be some problem with query

Comment: The query is actually correct, I always display it in a table (shopping cart), and it only retrieves the data related to the pProdutos, but only when deleting it does erase everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the trailing `.ref` you have at the end of your query here:

```
ref.where('pedido', '==', this.pProdutos)).ref
```

The first part `ref.where('pedido', '==', this.pProdutos))` constructs a query, but then calling `ref` on that query returns a `CollectionReference` to the entire collection. Remove the trailing `.ref` and it should work.

```
this.db.collection('produtosPedidos', ref => ref.where('pedido', '==', this.pProdutos))
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        ...
```

---

For this type of operation there is no additional benefit of running it through AngularFire. I recommend simply running it on the bare JavaScript SDK, to reduce the code a bit. Since AngularFire is built on top of the JavaScript SDK, the two interoperate perfectly when you do this.

In code:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('produtosPedidos').where('pedido', '==', this.pProdutos)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
```

Comment: it says "Property 'where' doesn't exist in 'AngularFirestoreCollection<{}>'". I think it's because im using this: " private db: AngularFirestore". How to fix?

Comment: Sorry about that, I replaced the call to AngularFire (`this.db.collection()`)  with a direct call to the JavaScript API (`firebase.firestore().collection(...)`).

Comment: How do I exactly call the import for 'firebase'? I forgot it.

Comment: I am not willing to use the fireAuth in this project, does importing the 'admin' thing causes any type of problems?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  deleteOffice(office) {
    this.firestore
      .collection('offices', (ref) => ref.where('name', '==', office.name))
      .get()
      .subscribe((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          doc.ref
            .delete()
            .then(() => {
              console.log('Document successfully deleted!');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.error('Error removing document: ', error);
            });
        });
      });
```